# Should the No-Overwrite extension be the normal behaviour?

Tags: contacts, user-account

I've seen cases where admin users have changed their contact details when adding someone else to an event.

I came across the [No Overwrite extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite), which makes First and Last names uneditable - great extension! Any reason why this shouldn't be the default behaviour?

Comment: I don't think this a good question for a q and a. Because it is less or more debatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the default behaviour is a tricky process, because some will want to keep the existing one as the default.

When I create a new site, I add a handful of "mandatory" extensions, like this one (glad you like it! ;), and it's my default, I think it's not too much of a trouble and allows everyone to have the civi tailored the way they want without disturbing the 10k other installations

X+

Answer (score 2):

Just being devil's advocate here, because I think the No Overwrite extension is great, but in the cases when you see your name somewhere and it's wrong, it's irritating if you can't fix it.  It may be a typo, or your first and/or last name may have changed due to one of a whole variety of life events that could have happened since the information was entered.

The alternative to allowing people to fix their names is to require a call or email to the office--staff time that costs nonprofits money.

Also, although I'm quite aware that many people ignore all this, it takes a certain amount of bravado to go on a form, blow past the warning box which offers to give you a blank form, and pro-actively replace a series of pre-populated fields.

Most individuals would never think of doing such a thing, and many charities have never had a problem like this.  On the other hand, it seems to be par for the course for trade association members.  That CiviCRM allows for either option (flexibility by default, or structure via Xavier's extension) is a real benefit.

Comment: The No Overwrite extension only freezes the name fields on contribution/membership/event pages.  If Drupal is your CMS then you can set up a CiviCRM profile that allows logged in users to edit their name on their Drupal user page. So for Drupal, at least, the No Overwrite extension stops people from accidentally overwriting their contact details when they sign someone else up for something, but they can still change their own name when they need to.

Comment: That's a great point, JoAnne.  A note on the contribution/event form could tell people to fix their information on the separate profile.